# FB iOS Login - "The app must ask for a basic_info permission at install time."

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an app in the AppStore with has calls to to openActiveSessionWithReadPermission that look like this:

```
  [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]
                                 allowLoginUI:YES
                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                              [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                            }];
```

The SDK version is 3.5. When upgrading to this newest version, I missed a key change in the login API which requires @"basic_info" to be requested in the readPermissions array. It isn't implicit any more.

It wasn't listed in the [updgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.2-to-3.5/), but I did find a small help box in the ['Technical Guide'](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/iossdk/login/) that talks about it.

> You may receive Developer Alerts if your app doesn't request
>   basic_info when requesting permissions from new users. In this case,
>   your app isn't eligible to use the Facebook app native Login dialog.
>   To stop receiving these alerts and take advantage of this dialog,
>   request basic_info for all new users and then visit your App
>   Dashboard's Advanced settings to enable this migration: ''Specify
>   basic_info for iOS login dialog''.

I see no such migration in my app settings for 'Specify basic_info for iOS login dialog.'

**So, my question(s):**

- Did this migration already expire? Did it ever exist?
- Is there anything I can do to solve this while I wait for a new version to get approved by Apple?
- Is there a way for me to temporarily force web-based authentication (like via Safari)?

I have the simple fix (include @"basic_info"), but looking for a patch to hold me over for a week or so.

Interestingly, people who connect via the iOS native FB auth thing don't experience the issue. It's only for people connecting through the FB native app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I work at FB on the platform product team and can help get this fixed for you without an update to your app.

We had to fix a (very unfortunate) bug that changed the behavior of the new native Login Dialog.  Apps need to pass @"basic_info" in the permission list for the dialog to display correctly.  For apps that made it into the store before this fix, we can make a server-side change to fix this for you.

When you get a chance, send me a Facebook message with your app ID.

Sincere apologies that your app is running into this.

Thanks,
Eddie

Comment: just sent you a message with my app id. thanks a million for reaching out to me!